# Install apps on Android Phone automatically when installed in BlueStacks

Tags: applications, installation, cloud, bluestacks

I am developing an Android application, and I have to constantly mail the apk to myself to download to phone. I also use Bluestacks app player for testing. But also verify app in my own phone. **Is there any way to have the app installed on the phone directly when installed on the Bluestacks App Player**. I know the reverse is possible through Bluestacks Cloud Connect. Can I achieve the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

With an installation of the official Android SDK, virtual devices are available to you (so you don't have to use Bluestacks).  You can simply install them via `adb` to your virtual Android device and test them there.  You can customize every aspect of the device, ranging from resolution, hardware buttons, modems, and software.

If you are developing using Eclipse, simply install the SDK and the plugins, and then press the "Play" button, and Eclipse will send the app directly to your phone.

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: That would apply to Bluestacks and any other Android emulator as well. I e.g. run Android-x86 in VirtualBox, and can access it fine via ADB.

Answer (score 0):

When there is any app installed through the Play Store(through your Gmail Account) the app gets listed under My Apps>Installed apps.

So instead of downloading it again from your mail separately (the apk file) you can directly download the apps through the installed my apps in your device(under options from the play store on your device).

For this you just need to login with the same account you had logged in with the blue stack. In this way you could at the least save the trouble from sending the apk file to the email and then again downloading it on your device.

Else you simply download the ADT to develop apps and later test it on you own device through the USB cable. For further questions regarding app development visit this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/)